# Authentication issue in SIP server

Tags: java, authentication, centos, sip, ubuntu-server

I am able to communicate with intranet SIP server and able to perform text chat / video & audio chat without issues. but it did not work at all when i moved the same setup to public domain on centOS dedicated server and ubuntu servers.

I tried the same setup in almost four servers, SIP server runs fine and I can't authenticate from users and below is suspected authorization issue. please advice if anything else :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root@ip-10-130-137-143:/home/ubuntu# netstat -lnptu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.130.137.143:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1588/kamailio
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5060          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1588/kamailio
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      752/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      628/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      628/sshd
udp        0      0 10.130.137.143:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           1566/kamailio
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5060          0.0.0.0:*                           1566/kamailio
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           421/dhclient3

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root@ip-10-130-137-143:/home/ubuntu# ngrep -p -q -W byline port 5060
interface: eth0 (10.130.137.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 5060 )

U 182.65.181.3:5060 -> 10.130.137.143:5060
REGISTER sip:54.251.243.10 SIP/2.0.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 1 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-ffcd7de8d4032279df0bf50bc606776c.
Max-Forwards: 70.
User-Agent: Jitsi2.2.4603.9615Windows 7.
Expires: 600.
Contact: "vijay" <sip:vijay@192.168.0.107:5060;transport=udp;registering_acc=54_251_243_10>;expires=600.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 10.130.137.143:5060 -> 182.65.181.3:5060
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 1 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.6006.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-ffcd7de8d4032279df0bf50bc606776c;received=182.65.181.3.
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="54.251.243.10", nonce="UfX6g1H1+Vf1PJF95KZYQuU+RvZsHV6u".
Server: kamailio (4.0.2 (x86_64/linux)).
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 182.65.181.3:5060 -> 10.130.137.143:5060
REGISTER sip:54.251.243.10 SIP/2.0.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 2 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>.
Max-Forwards: 70.
User-Agent: Jitsi2.2.4603.9615Windows 7.
Expires: 600.
Contact: "vijay" <sip:vijay@192.168.0.107:5060;transport=udp;registering_acc=54_251_243_10>;expires=600.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-dd9c63d103bebfec91b34722d0df1607.
Authorization: Digest username="vijay",realm="54.251.243.10",nonce="UfX6g1H1+Vf1PJF95KZYQuU+RvZsHV6u",uri="sip:54.251.243.10",response="25f103c48f491c3d9c274088b5efcfa0".
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 10.130.137.143:5060 -> 182.65.181.3:5060
SIP/2.0 403 Not relaying.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 2 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.ff09.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-dd9c63d103bebfec91b34722d0df1607;received=182.65.181.3.
Server: kamailio (4.0.2 (x86_64/linux)).
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 182.65.181.3:5060 -> 10.130.137.143:5060
REGISTER sip:54.251.243.10 SIP/2.0.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 3 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>.
Max-Forwards: 70.
User-Agent: Jitsi2.2.4603.9615Windows 7.
Expires: 600.
Contact: "vijay" <sip:vijay@192.168.0.107:5060;transport=udp;registering_acc=54_251_243_10>;expires=600.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-630ada674eec24c25e106288f1de871f.
Content-Length: 0.
.


U 10.130.137.143:5060 -> 182.65.181.3:5060
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized.
Call-ID: 01a9d12a1c5a30e472fe6479e8c2fd51@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
CSeq: 3 REGISTER.
From: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=f5fcb710.
To: "vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.90cb.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.107:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-393933-630ada674eec24c25e106288f1de871f;received=182.65.181.3.
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="54.251.243.10", nonce="UfX6i1H1+V++hTJe2yLYBqYaqRF7F5Xo".
Server: kamailio (4.0.2 (x86_64/linux)).
Content-Length: 0.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I enabled the dubug mode and error message is 

17(1588) DEBUG: <core> [io_wait.h:390]: io_watch_add(): DBG: io_watch_add(0x89cca0, 27, 3, 0x7f46bd3c57b0), fd_no=19
17(1588) DEBUG: <core> [io_wait.h:390]: io_watch_add(): DBG: io_watch_add(0x89cca0, 29, 3, 0x7f46bd3c57d0), fd_no=20
17(1588) DEBUG: <core> [io_wait.h:390]: io_watch_add(): DBG: io_watch_add(0x89cca0, 31, 3, 0x7f46bd3c57f0), fd_no=21
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:623]: parse_msg(): SIP Request:
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:625]: parse_msg():  method:  <REGISTER>
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:627]: parse_msg():  uri:     <sip:54.251.243.10>
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:629]: parse_msg():  version: <SIP/2.0>
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:170]: get_hdr_field(): get_hdr_field: cseq <CSeq>: <1> <REGISTER>
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/parse_to.c:799]: parse_to(): end of header reached, state=10
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:190]: get_hdr_field(): DEBUG: get_hdr_field: <To> [35]; uri=[sip:vijay@54.251.243.10]
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:192]: get_hdr_field(): DEBUG: to body ["vijay" <sip:vijay@54.251.243.10>
]
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/parse_via.c:1284]: parse_via_param(): Found param type 232, <branch> = <z9hG4bK-393933-ffcd7de8d4032279df0bf50bc606776c>; state=16
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/parse_via.c:2672]: parse_via(): end of header reached, state=5
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:513]: parse_headers(): parse_headers: Via found, flags=2
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:515]: parse_headers(): parse_headers: this is the first via
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [receive.c:149]: receive_msg(): After parse_msg...
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [receive.c:190]: receive_msg(): preparing to run routing scripts...
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=464 a=5 n=route
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=574 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=569 a=25 n=mf_process_maxfwd_header
8(1575) DEBUG: maxfwd [mf_funcs.c:85]: is_maxfwd_present(): value = 70
8(1575) DEBUG: maxfwd [maxfwd.c:161]: process_maxfwd_header(): value 70 decreased to 16
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=579 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=574 a=26 n=sanity_check
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:204]: get_hdr_field(): DEBUG: get_hdr_body : content_length=0
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:106]: get_hdr_field(): found end of header
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/parse_to.c:176]: parse_to_param(): DEBUG: add_param: tag=f5fcb710
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [parser/parse_to.c:799]: parse_to(): end of header reached, state=29
8(1575) DEBUG: sanity [mod_sanity.c:255]: w_sanity_check(): sanity checks result: 1
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=467 a=5 n=route
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=767 a=2 n=return
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=479 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=470 a=25 n=is_method
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=479 a=5 n=route
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=623 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=583 a=24 n=has_totag
8(1575) DEBUG: siputils [checks.c:103]: has_totag(): no totag
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=483 a=24 n=t_check_trans
8(1575) DEBUG: tm [t_lookup.c:1095]: t_check_msg(): DEBUG: t_check_msg: msg id=1 global id=0 T start=0xffffffffffffffff
8(1575) DEBUG: tm [t_lookup.c:534]: t_lookup_request(): t_lookup_request: start searching: hash=38419, isACK=0
8(1575) DEBUG: tm [t_lookup.c:492]: matching_3261(): DEBUG: RFC3261 transaction matching failed
8(1575) DEBUG: tm [t_lookup.c:716]: t_lookup_request(): DEBUG: t_lookup_request: no transaction found
8(1575) DEBUG: tm [t_lookup.c:1164]: t_check_msg(): DEBUG: t_check_msg: msg id=1 global id=1 T end=(nil)
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=486 a=5 n=route
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=744 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=731 a=25 n=is_method
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=739 a=16 n=if
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=734 a=27 n=auth_check
8(1575) DEBUG: auth_db [authorize.c:476]: auth_check(): realm [54.251.243.10] table [subscriber] flags [1]
8(1575) DEBUG: auth [api.c:86]: pre_auth(): auth:pre_auth: Credentials with realm '54.251.243.10' not found
8(1575) DEBUG: auth_db [authorize.c:252]: digest_authenticate(): no credentials
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=735 a=26 n=auth_challenge
8(1575) DEBUG: auth [challenge.c:127]: get_challenge_hf(): build_challenge_hf: realm='54.251.243.10'
8(1575) DEBUG: auth [challenge.c:269]: get_challenge_hf(): auth: 'WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="54.251.243.10", nonce="UfX6g1H1+Vf1PJF95KZYQuU+RvZsHV6u"
'
8(1575) DEBUG: sl [sl.c:289]: send_reply(): reply in stateless mode (sl)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [msg_translator.c:206]: check_via_address(): check_via_address(182.65.181.3, 192.168.0.107, 0)
8(1575) ERROR: *** cfgtrace: c=[/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg] l=736 a=2 n=exit
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [usr_avp.c:644]: destroy_avp_list(): DEBUG:destroy_avp_list: destroying list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [xavp.c:447]: xavp_destroy_list(): destroying xavp list (nil)
8(1575) DEBUG: <core> [receive.c:293]: receive_msg(): receive_msg: cleaning up
```

Answer (score 1):

The SIP response '403 Not relaying' is sent because none of the domains in From URI and request URI is local IP (or hostname). For security reasons, either sender or destination must be a local user or service (using server's IP or hostnames), otherwise the instance can be used as open relay to target other hosts.

You can specify the list of local domains via 'alias' global parameter in kamailio.cfg or using domain module.

From your SIP trace and netstat output, seems that Kamailio is listening on 10.130.137.143, but the From/R-URI domain is 54.251.243.10.

In case kamailio is running on a natted server and the traffic is forwarded from a public ip via a firewall (something similar like running Kamailio on Amazon EC2), then you should use advertise for your listen parameters in config, like:

```
listen=udp:10.130.137.143:5060 advertise 54.251.243.10:5060
```

For more details, see:

- http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/devel/core#listen